# Is it safe to use a HydroFlask (vacuum flask) with scratches on the inside?

Tags: cleaning, safety

When I was washing my HydroFlask out before the first use, I put a wet paper towel on the inside of the bottle and used the handle of wooden spoon to push the towel around the very bottom. When I took the towel back out, I noticed a new crescent-shaped blemish/discoloration from where I was sliding the towel with the spoon handle and this blemish will not come out. Upon further inspection, this blemish *does* appear to be an actual scratch, as water drops stick to it when they don't stick anywhere else on the interior of the bottle.

I am really shocked that such an action would have scratched it in the first place, as the wooden handle never came in direct contact with the bottle. There were several layers of wet paper towel between it and the bottle interior.

Does this scratch compromise the integrity or safety of the bottle? Like will the finish start to wear away and get into the liquid contents of the bottle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hydro Flasks don't have an interior lining, they're just food grade stainless steel. You'll be perfectly fine using the bottle as you would otherwise.